# ARCore: ImageManagerOnTrackedImagesChanged referenceImage.name is null in XRSimulation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

I'm trying to make an image tracking AR on Unity version 2022.3.21f1 and simulated it on Unity itself with XREnvironment since my device is incompatible. But when the image's name is debugged, it always prints `null`. Printing the image's guid value always result to `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I found the same issue here, might this be a bug? https://forum.unity.com/threads/arfoundation-imagetracking-with-worldmap.1049984/

my ImageTrackingObjectManager.cs file:

```cs
void ImageManagerOnTrackedImagesChanged(ARTrackedImagesChangedEventArgs obj) {
    // added, spawn prefab
    foreach(ARTrackedImage image in obj.added) {
        Debug.Log(image.referenceImage.name); // prints "null"

        if (image.referenceImage.name == "TrackedImage1") {
            // ...
        }
        else if (image.referenceImage.name == "TrackedImage2") {
            // ...
        }
    }
    
    foreach(ARTrackedImage image in obj.updated) {
        // ...
    }
    
    foreach(ARTrackedImage image in obj.removed) {
        
        // ...
    }
}
```

my reference image library:

[image]

my XR environment:

[image]